# Changing the URL/IP of AngularJS ngresource in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, resources, factory, ngresource

I would like to use the user-selected IP address to change the REST URL more than one time, it may have serval server IP addresses, but after the factory file was loaded immediately after the app start, the IP addresses (`$rootScope.baseURL`) cannot be changed.

Is there any way I can change the path again?

P.S. console.log(`$rootScope.baseURL`) can successfully output the value, but after the return part, it is not working.

**Controller:**

```
$scope.authenticateUser = function(){
      $rootScope.$broadcast('ipChanged', $scope.user.ip);
}
```

**Factory:**

```
.factory( 'Models', function ($rootScope, $resource, Constants) {

        $rootScope.$on('ipChanged', function(event, data) {
            $rootScope.baseURL = "http://" + data + "/rest"
            console.log("$rootScope.baseURL")
        });

     return{
            appMaster_user_session: $resource($rootScope.baseURL + '/user/session',
                {
                    app_name: Constants.API.appName
                },
                {
                    'post': {method:'POST'},
                    'put': {method: 'PUT'}
                }
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a service configurable by using a [provider recipe](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers).

```
myApp.provider('Models', function ModelsProvider() {
  var apiUrl = 'http://www.deafault.com';

  this.apiUrl = function(value) {
    apiUrl = value;
  };

  this.$get = [function modelsFactory() {
    return {
        appMaster_user_session: $resource(apiUrl  + '/user/session',
            {
                app_name: Constants.API.appName
            },
            {
                'post': {method:'POST'},
                'put': {method: 'PUT'}
            }
        )
     }
  }];
});
```

You need to set apiUrl in config section of your module.

if you want to get a different url each time you could make this resource contain a function that recieves apiUrl.

```
myApp.provider('Models', function ModelsProvider() { 
  this.$get = [function modelsFactory() {
    return {
        getSessionResource: function(apiUrl) {
          return $resource(apiUrl  + '/user/session',
            {
                app_name: Constants.API.appName
            },
            {
                'post': {method:'POST'},
                'put': {method: 'PUT'}
            }
        )
     }
  }];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem using the URL parameter in ngresource action, it can override the old value after the ngresource was initiated.